# Bootstrap Select Drop Down is not Vertically Listed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-selectpicker

I tried to use bootstrap-select to implement a drop down box, but the options are not vertically listed. Did anyone have the same issue before?

```
    <script src="{% static 'risk_parity/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'risk_parity/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <link href="{% static 'risk_parity/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <select class="selectpicker" >
                        <option>USA</option>
                        <option>CA</option>                     
                    </select>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){           
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });

</script>
```

[Not Vertically Listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rewwh.png)

Comment: what dropdown box? do you mean the select dropdown you're adding with `selectpicker()`?

Comment: Yes, DelightedD0D. I attached a picture there for your reference. It is horizontally listed right now and I would like to make them vertically listed.

Comment: You must have some extra css affecting that element,  the code works fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/74/, right click the element and find the css rule that is causing the issue and change it

Comment: see the console for errors, i guess your js or css is not loaded properly

Comment: @Exprator why would you say that? seems like a simple css clash

Comment: @DelightedD0D he is not using any custom css that would clash, :)

Comment: @Exprator look at the image, I assure you that he is, even if he isnt showing it here ;)

Comment: @DavidYang : Did you change anything in `bootstrap.min.css` file or have you added any inline css in page, because apart from this its working fine when I use `bootstrap CDN` file.

Comment: Inspect the `li` of the menu in Chrome and show us the CSS. You probably have `display: inline-block;` somewhere applied to all `li`'s

Comment: Thank you for all the helps guys! My li's that were controlling the nav bar were causing the conflicting. Now the problem is solved after I have modified them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please find below , Its working perfect. It seems like you might have changed bootstrap's default CSS or you have added inline css hence this occurs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){           
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

    <select class="selectpicker" >
       <option>USA</option>
       <option>CA</option>                     
    </select>
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: The OP has some other CSS affecting the element, this wouldnt fix that

Comment: @DelightedD0D: This is what the question is, Everything is working fine, he need to share other css which causing this issue. But meanwhile you downvoted my answer.

Comment: Yes I did, because this answer does nothing to address the issue. You've simply replaced the relative resource links for absolute ones, there is no reason to believe that would fix this css clash issue

Comment: @DelightedD0D : He might changed Bootstrap's default CSS or added custom inline css, hence this issue occurs. Here I given path of CDN and it works perfect. Please think and view my answer again.

Comment: If the OP has modified Bootstrap (not advised, you should overwrite not modify the library) but lets say he did, if so, he likely *needs* those changes elsewhere, therefore simply changing to a CDN version is very likely to fix this and break something else. The OP needs to find the clashing CSS rule and fix it correctly. This can easily be done by simply right clicking the element and viewing the applied styles. Your answer mentions none of this.

Comment: @DelightedD0D : Thats what I have asked in comments below question. If he did  than he can share, Even I can inspect an give him solution but I can not check in his browser that what he did wrong or anything else. So I asked him already.

Comment: @ShyamShingadiya is right. If the example works here with the code OP has provided and the issue is elsewhere it makes no sense to try to answer him if he doesn't post more code/css.